# king of Tokyo- camouflage

Tags: king-of-tokyo

If I buy a card that does damage to me, and I have camouflage, do I get to roll to negate that damage? The card says when I take damage I roll to negate it, so I would think I could get rid of the damage by rolling hearts.

> Camouflage: If you take damage, roll a die, on a heart roll you do not take the damage. You roll once die for each damage you take. Does this apply to damage from cards?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Your doubts probably stem from thinking about the cards that react to attacks. Damage from cards aren't attacks, so those cards don't react to damage from cards. However, Camouflage doesn't mention attacks, only damage. As such, there's no reason for it not to function in the scenario you describe.